# Linq Join vs .Where().DefaultIfEmpty()

Tags: linq-to-sql

Getting to grips with Linq and I have a query that contains alot of joins to other tables.

I won't put the whole query here as it's not really relevant to my actual question.

I'm wondering which is the better way to write my query and why?

Query 1 :

```
var query = from team in context.tblTeams
            join manager in context.tblManagers on team.fkManager equals manager.pkManager into managerJoin
            from manager in managerJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join colour in context.tblTeamColours on team.fkTeamColour equals colour.pkTeamColour into colourJoin
            from colour in colourJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join sponser in context.tblSponsers on team.fkSponser equals sponser.pkSponser into sponserJoin
            from sponser in sponserJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new TeamView
            {
                pkTeam = team.pkTeam,
                strManager = manager.strManagerName,
                strTeamColour = colour.strColour,
                strSponser = sponser.strSponser
            };
```

Query 2:

```
var query = from team in context.tblTeams
            from manager in context.tblManagers.Where(x => x.pkManager == team.fkManager).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from colour in context.tblTeamColours.Where(x => x.pkTeamColour == team.fkTeamColour).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from sponser in context.tblSponsers.Where(x => x.pkSponser == team.fkSponser).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new TeamView
            {
                pkTeam = team.pkTeam,
                strManager = manager.strManagerName,
                strTeamColour = colour.strColour,
                strSponser = sponser.strSponser
            };
```

They both seem to take pretty much the same amount of time to run. I'm just wondering if there is any difference other than readability?

With 33 joins in the full query the second method seems neater and easier to read to me.

Alternatively, how else can I write the query which could make it faster?

Comment: First and foremost: use navigation properties, not joins.

Comment: With 33 joins, I think you could only make it faster by re-designing your table structure or query to need fewer joins. I think you will need to examine the SQL translation of the queries and determine what is faster for the SQL Engine you are using, or if they are equivalent.

Comment: OK using the navigation properties has halved the time it took to return results! And much neater. I feel a bit stupid for not trying that in the first place.